# 'scrapy' is not recognized as an internal or external command after installation

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using python version 3.7. I installed the package scrapy using the command `pip install scrapy` which got installed along with other dependencies successfully.

I then ran the command `scrapy startproject newproject`, this resulted into an error that reads `'scrapy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

I also ran the command `scrapy` on the command line, it gave the same error.

**Note**: when I ran the command `pip list`, scrapy was among the installed packages.

How can i fix this please?

Answer (score 2):

So, I was able to solve the method using **two different methods**:

The **first method** includes the following:

1. I installed it using anaconda with the command `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`, and then activated the conda environment using conda activate.
2. After running `scrapy startproject newproject` this time, it worked successfully.

**Note**: You need to have anaconda or miniconda installed for this to work successfully.

The **second method** includes the following:

1. I created a virtual environment using the command `python -m venv venv` and then activated it using the command `venv\scripts\activate`.
2. I ran the command `pip install scrapy`. I got an error here `error: can't find Rust compiler`, i was using the pip version: 19.0.3. So I solved the issue by upgrading the pip version by using th command `pip install --upgrade pip` which upgraded it to the version `pip 21.1.2`
3. so after running the `pip install scrapy` command again, it worked successfully.

Throughout the whole process I noticed that, the scrapy command didn't work without being activated in a virtual environment even though the installation worked.